# Error in eval: object of dateRangeInput not found

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create an app, where a user chooses appropriate dates which later serves as a filter for displaying and aggregating a chosen dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

start_date <- "2019-06-30"
end_date <- "2021-06-30"

VP_all <- data.frame(code= c("VP001", "VP002", "VP003", "VP004", "VP005", "VP006", "VP007", "VP008"),
                     available = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), 
                     date = c("2019-09-28", "2021-09-28", "2024-07-12", "2022-11-03", "2021-11-26", "2019-09-28", "2021-09-28", "2024-07-12"))

#Recovery option 5 specific function
select <- function(df, x){
  VP_EB <- subset(df, df$available == "Yes" & df$date > x)

  return(VP_EB)
}

#################################
#UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

   tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Settings",
               br(),
               column(width = 8,
                      box(title = "Set parameters", id = "RO_05_param_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE, status ="primary", collapsible = TRUE,
                          box(dateRangeInput("date_range_view", h6("Determine the sell period"), start = start_date, end = end_date, min = start_date, max = end_date),
                          dateRangeInput("date_range_view2", h6("Determine the repurchase period"), start = start_date, end = end_date, min = start_date, max = end_date))
                          )
                 ),
                 column(width = 12,
                        box(title = "Review available financial assets", id = "RO_05_rewiew_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", collapsed = FALSE, collapsible = TRUE, 
                            dataTableOutput("RO_05_available"))
                        )
               )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   observe({
     output$RO_05_available <- renderDataTable({
       df_RO05 <- select(VP_all, date_range_view2[2])
       },options = list(scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = "400px"))
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I keep getting error

> Error in eval: object 'date_range_view2' not found

I tried with `select(VP_all, req(date_range_view2[2]))`, but that doesn't work either - however I think it is not necessary since values of date_range_view2 are set in ui.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You reference a UI input by using `input$date_range_view2`

Comment: Of course, it does! Thx.